# PowerBI Cx error connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, connection, database-connection, npgsql, powerbi

This is the error I received when attempting to connect to a PostgreSQL db using power bi

Details: "TlsClientStream.ClientAlertException: CertificateExpired
  at TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.SendAlertFatal(AlertDescription
description, String message)
   at TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[]
buf,Int32&poa)
   at TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandchakeMessages()
    at TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.GetInitialHandshakeMessages
(Boolean allowApplicationData)
   at TlsClientStream.TlsClientStream.PerformIntitialHandshake(String
Hostname, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates,
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
remoteeCertificateValidationCallback, Boolean
checkCertificateRevocation)"

I couldn't find the answer anywhere on stackoverflow.

PostgreSQL is located remotely and I downloaded Version: 2.33.4337.501 64-bit of PowerBI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dropping back to Npgsql 2.x, it's worth spending a few minutes [on the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html):

> Note that by default, Npgsql will verify that your server’s
>   certificate is valid. If you’re using a self-signed certificate this
>   will fail. You can instruct Npgsql to ignore this by specifying Trust
>   Server Certificate=true in the connection string. To precisely control
>   how the server’s certificate is validated, you can register
>   UserCertificateValidationCallback on NpgsqlConnection (this works just
>   like on .NET’s SSLStream).

Answer (score -1):

I am answering my own question because I did put in considerable amount of time, and I hope other people don't need to waste the same amount of time for such simple solution.

Basically the problem was with the version of npgsql I used. 
At the time of this post, the version I used was Npgsql 3.0.7, which by default is to perform validation while the 2.x versions didn't perform validation on the server's certificate by default. The connection works after uninstall and install the 2.x version. This solution is no good for people who have to use the 3.x version.

Comment: Npgsql 2.x is ancient by now, and you shouldn't use it unless you have a really good reason.